# Docker - access existing container files on host machine

Tags: docker

I have a docker container which has some data in let's say /opt/files. File A and B. How can I start that container and access these files on my host machine?

I'm using Docker for Windows (Hyper-V). When i start the container with:

```
docker run -it -v C:/tmp:/opt/files myImage
```

I see an empty folder on my windows machine and inside of the container. Any new files I create there are of course reflected on both sides but how can I access files that are already in the container (e.g. because they're added in the Dockerfile)?

Comment: You can share from inside to host. So you have two options, one is share another folder and copy the files to same by going inside the container. Or else use `docker cp` to get the files out of container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't share from inside container to host.  There are two ways to do it

**Copy the files from container**

```
docker cp <containerid>:<file_path_inside_container> localpath
```

**Share a folder other than the one where files will be generated**

```
docker run -it -v C:/tmp:/opt/files_temp myImage
```

Then you get inside the container copy files from `/opt/files` to `/opt/files_temp`

Answer (score 1):

Once your container is started, you can copy files inside it to your host.

Use `docker cp` for this (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).

Example : `docker cp CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-`